# CSS Image Filter Override

Tags: css, google-chrome, filter

Whenever I try and add a filter to an image on my page I get that filter crossed off...I've tried adding in my CSS file, but the same thing happens...any idea what could be causing this? [image]

Comment: Perhaps it want's a browser specific declaration like " -webkit-filter:grayscale(10%); " ? I just tried it on a random site in chrome and it worked like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Chrome, please add vendor specific -webkit for filter.

```
#turbo-dog {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: grayscale(10%);
}
```